# Adding new class in framework via SDK-Addon: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, frameworks, sdk, add-on

I am trying to introduce a new API on the custom android 4.0.3 image.

I have used the \device\sample project and created a new device sdk-addon based on it,

I have added my own java add-on library code and the build is happens perfectly fine, when compiled with 'make PRODUCT-mysample_addon-sdk_​addon'

The output is available in the out\host\linux-x86\sdk_addon\ as a ZIP file

I am able to install the zip file in the sdk add-on directory, create new avd with my custom add-on and launch the emulator.

When I create new android UI application using the new add-on I created, the application builds using my new custom API but when I try to run it on device, the addon class is not found and I get java.lang.​NoClassDefFoundError.

The Jar and odex are located in /system/framework directory, the JAR file contains only the manifest the ODEX contains the actual class information.

I am not sure what more entries needs to be done, I got hint from someone that adding the class reference in BOOTCLASSPATH in init.rc will help, I have also tried but it does not seems to work.

Please suggest if you have any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution answered elsewhere was to add

```
<uses-library android:name="<library-package>"/>
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml` of the application.